# How can I test the value of a static attribute with JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have the following Job class:

```
 public class Job {
    static int jobTotal = 0;

    private int jobNumber;
    private Address location;
    private String description;
    private List<Equipment> requiredEquipment;
    private Date plannedDate;

    public static int getJobTotal() {
        return jobTotal;
    }
 }
```

This class contains a bunch of other methods, but getJobTotal is the only one that is relevant in this case.

Inside JobTest.java I run a couple of tests for each of these methods (there are around 14 test methods):

```
class JobTest {
    Job j1;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        Address a = new Address("street", 111, "zip", "city");
        ArrayList<Equipment> equipment = new ArrayList<>();
        equipment.add(new Torch("Don't turn on or it explodes"));
        j1 = new Job(a, "Replace lightbulb", equipment, new Date(15, 10, 2023));
    }

    @Test
    void testConstructor() {
        assertFalse(j1 == null);
    }

    @Test
    void getJobTotal() {
        //? How do I test for getJobTotal?
    }
}
```

However, tests are not ran in the order in which they are defined inside the test file. As a result, my BeforeEach could trigger an unknown amount of times before reaching getJobTotal(the test method I mean).

How could I test that the getter returns a "correct" value? Because I can't really place any value inside the "expected" parameter of assertEquals().

PS: I am using JUnit 5

Comment: In my opinion, you're doing too much work in `init()`, and your test in `testConstructor()` makes no sense: a constructor is guaranteed to return an object, or end abruptly with an exception. If an exception would have been thrown, your test method would not have been called. In any case, there doesn't seem to be anything to test for `jobTotal`, as your code doesn't modify it, so it is always 0. It also doesn't look like the right abstraction to me.

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677467/junit-do-static-classes-maintain-state-between-test-classes

Comment: Beware of concurrent modification of this value. Consider using AtomicInteger instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the value of a static attribute like jobTotal in your Job class using JUnit 5, you can use the @BeforeAll and @AfterAll annotations to set and reset the value. These annotations are used for setup and cleanup methods that run once before and after all the test methods in a test class. Here's how you can do it.

```
@BeforeEach
void init() {
    Address a = new Address("street", 111, "zip", "city");
    ArrayList<Equipment> equipment = new ArrayList<>();
    equipment.add(new Torch("Don't turn on or it explodes"));
    j1 = new Job(a, "Replace lightbulb", equipment, new Date(15, 10, 2023));
}

@Test
void testConstructor() {
    assertFalse(j1 == null);
}

@Test
void testGetJobTotal() {
    // Assuming you have set up some jobs, you can test the static attribute like this:
    int initialTotal = Job.getJobTotal();
    
    // Perform actions that change the jobTotal, e.g., creating more jobs

    int updatedTotal = Job.getJobTotal();

    // Now you can assert the values
    assertEquals(initialTotal + 1, updatedTotal); // Or any expected value based on your test scenario
}

@BeforeAll
static void setup() {
    // Initialize or set up anything needed before running the tests
}

@AfterAll
static void cleanup() {
    // Clean up or reset any state that was changed during testing
}
```

}