# Can I add a junit listener that can be invoked between test classes, rather than between test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, junit-runner

I am having a problem where unit tests are modifying the static state of class `Foo` and not cleaning up after themselves. This means that a unit test may pass when it is run by itself, but fail when some other unit test runs before it, because the state has changed.

I've been going through the code looking for those tests that change the static state of `Foo` and adding the necessary clean ups, but then I had another idea: why not use a junit test listener to examine the static state of `Foo` after each test has run, and fail if `Foo` is left in a modified state? Then I automatically get a list of naughty tests with each build, and can identify any similar problems in the future.

So I implemented a junit `RunListener` and modified my `pom.xml` to add the listener to the `maven-surefire-plugin`, and verified that the listener is executed for each test case.

The simple solution is to override the `testFinished()` method of `RunListener` and check the static state:

```
public class FooChecker extends RunListener {
  @Override
  public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    if (fooClassInModifiedState()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Test " + description.getDisplayName()
            + " has left Foo in a modified state");
    }
  }
}
```

This will work on tests of the following form:

```
public class SomeTest {

  @Before
  public void setUpTest() {
    Foo.modifyState();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDownTest() {
    Foo.resetState();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCase1() {
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testCase2() {
    ...
  }
```

}

After each test case, the `@After` method is invoked and cleans up the state. Then the `testFinished()` method of the junit run listener is invoked, and verifies that the state has been reset. If I remove the `@After` method, then the run listener will raise an error, as expected.

The problem here is that the `testFinished` method of the junit run listener is called after the `@BeforeClass` and before any `@AfterClass` methods of the unit test. If the unit test modifies the state of Foo in a `@BeforeClass` and cleans up in an `@AfterClass` method, then the `testFinished` method of the listener will see the modified state and incorrectly raise an error:

```
public class SomeTest {

  @BeforeClass
  public void setUpClass() {
    Foo.modifyState();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCase1() {
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testCase2() {
    ...
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void tearDownClass() {
    Foo.resetState();
  }

}
```

Here, the `testFinished()` method of the run listener is invoked after `testCase1()` and `testCase2()` have been invoked, but before the `@AfterClass` method is invoked, so the state of `Foo` is still modified, and the run listener will raise an error. That is not the correct behaviour.

In general, for two unit tests `TestA` and `TestB`, and a junit run listener `Listener`, the calling sequence seems to be:

- Listener.testRunStarted()
- TestA.@BeforeClass
- Listener.testStarted("TestA.testCase1)
- TestA.@Before
- TestA.testCase1()
- TestA.@After
- Listener.testFinished(TestA.testCase1)
- Listener.testStarted("TestA.testCase2)
- TestA.@Before
- TestA.testCase2()
- TestA.@After
- Listener.testFinished(TestA.testCase2)
- TestA.@AfterClass
- TestB.@BeforeClass
- Listener.testStarted("TestB.testCase1)
- TestB.@Before
- TestB.testCase1()
- TestB.@After
- Listener.testFinished(TestB.testCase1)
- TestB.@AfterClass
- Listener.testRunFinished()

What I'd like is to perform the check of modified state after the `@AfterClass` method has been invoked for a unit test, and before the `@BeforeClass` method is invoked on the next unit test. This way I can ensure that a unit test (if not the individual test cases) perform the necessary cleanup and still respect the test semantics.

But I can't see a way to do this using the junit `RunListener` and invoking tests using maven surefire plugin.

Is there a solution here?

edit: Adding a junit class rule to existing tests that checks the state is not an option, because I would need to add it to every test that exists now and every test that is added in the future. I want something that will automagically discover any violations, if possible.

edit: the underlying issue here is that each unit test for the maven module is run in the same JVM. I tried running each unit test in its own JVM (via setting the forking options of surefire) but the tests took too long to run. So I am stuck with a single JVM  for multiple unit tests.

edit: Of course using static methods is bad design in the first place, and refactoring to inject state would be preferred, but refactoring a legacy code base of 1,000,000+ lines is not an option at this stage.

Comment: try testng http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/

Comment: A related resource: [Using different classloaders for different JUnit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42102/474189). This technique can "reset" static classes for each test class (but sadly not each test method).

Comment: Have you considered whether refactoring might allow you to test your code without invoking (and changing) static data? You are going to a lot of effort to try and resolve this issue, whereas in many cases it can be side-stepped. Perhaps you can share some details of your class and we could advise in that area too?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on refactoring, but as much as I'd prefer to refactor the code to get rid of any static dependencies, I'm afraid that (for various reasons) this is not an option right now.

Comment: The separate class loader per unit test is a neat idea, but it means modifying existing and future unit tests to use a specific junit runner rather than being a transparent process, and some unit tests are already using other junit runners (e.g. using PowerMock), so unfortunately I don't think it is an option right now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion of testng, but migrating the existing unit tests from junit to testng is not an option, unfortunately.