# Run each JUnit Test with a Separate ClassLoader (no, really)

Tags: java, junit, classloader, test-runner

How can I have JUnit use a separate `ClassLoader` for each test class it executes?

I am writing a JUnit `TestRunner` for a library that sets a lot of static variables. I essentially want to reset all of these between each test class, without needing to know what all of them are. I do not want to be coupled to intimate knowledge of the framework, as whenever the library changes internally then my `TestRunner` will break.

Before I go any further, I want to make absolutely clear that I *really do* want to do this.

- I do not have control over the library.
- I do not have the option of not using static variables.
- I do not want to use reflection or Powermock, as I don't *want* to know what's going on in the library.
- I do not want to use Maven config to fork testing processes, as then the testing utility is tied to a build tool.

Every other answer I can find on StackOverflow just says "don't do that," which isn't helpful. First person to answer with "static variables are dumb" wins a doughnut.

Comment: I want a doughnut!  "Static variables are dumb"

Comment: You win sir! Put your name and address in a Singleton that extends String on GitHub and I'll post it to you.

Comment: Hold on let me fork log4j and throw it in there.

Comment: Have you considered using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice)? It really helps you to avoid using static variables and helps you write much more cleaner code :)

Comment: Have you considered that there might be a dog loose in the woods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the end I wrote my own, loosely based on [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192126/774395) (which didn't work for me).

It's now on GitHub, and Maven Central.
https://github.com/BinaryTweed/quarantining-test-runner

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.binarytweed</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarantining-test-runner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To use it annotate your test classes accordingly:

```
@RunWith(QuarantiningRunner.class)
@Quarantine({"com.binarytweed"})
public class MyIsolatedTest {
...
```

The linked answer didn't work for me as the test class itself needs to be loaded in a separate `ClassLoader`, as then all the classes it references will use the same loader. Quarantining is inclusive (rather than exclusive) as you need the JUnit `@Test` annotations to be loaded by the parent `ClassLoader`, otherwise JUnit can't find any testable methods as it uses `Class<Test>` as a key in a lookup map.

Answer (score 2):

MyFaces has a [TestPerClassLoaderRunner](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/test/trunk/test12/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/test/runners/TestPerClassLoaderRunner.java) which is (despite its name) what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, and it fails to find `java.lang.Object`! I think maybe I need to pass through the 'current' classpath to it...

Comment: Did you start it from Maven? Looks like it is very specific to its class path structure.

Comment: Nah, Eclipse. Will give that a go, and if it works then see if I can make it generic enough to work from either.