# IntelliJ running tests one by one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

To be short - I' just wrote a singleton class. Like the all singletons consists my singleton of a private constructor and a static field containing a predefined amount of objects of the class.

The case is - the singleton class has to be initialized using a JSON file and the expected behavior is it throwing an exception when no files from a given list are present.

The problem is that apparently IntelliJ (or maybe just JUnit) is loading all test classes and then executing them one by one in one program in a random order. This means that by the time the class which test the wrong initialization has been reached, the singleton already has been initialized. This means that every time I run all the tests at once I'll have one test which did not pass and when I run them one by one manually it'll result in all the tests passing.

Is there a way to force IntelliJ to run all the test classes separated?

**Edit**

I don't know how this could change anything, but lets assume it will. Here is a sample code with the exact same behavior. It's an IDE question, not a java speciffic one.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    private Singleton() {
        if (!new File("maybeIExist.txt").exists())
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("stuff");
    }
}
```

And of course the tests:

```
public class SingletonTestOne {
    @Test(expected = ExceptionInInitializerError.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Singleton.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And the second one:

```
public class SingletonTestTwo {
    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        //code creating file
    }
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Singleton.getInstance();
        doStuff();
    }
    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        //code deleting file
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the code of your singleton class.

Comment: I added it. I don't know how the code added anything to the question, but here you have it.

Comment: You should try [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order)

Comment: @ahrytsiuk I have the methods grouped in different classes, because they check different behavior. Is there something like that, but for classes? I need to use the singleton in another test case and it is initialized there, before it enters the wrong initialization test.

Comment: Theoretically, unit tests should be independent and this is perhaps why [JUnit does not guarantee their order](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order). There is a [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4) where execution order is discussed, but I don't think it will be useful. Under the circumstances perhaps [using a new classloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102/using-different-classloaders-for-different-junit-tests) to test your specific singleton happy/sad path may be the way to go

Comment: I don't need them to be in an specific order. They only have to execute separated instead of being run in one go.

Comment: this is not a problem which is located in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an IntelliJ problem, you would encounter the same when running `mvn test`. You can get the tests running with the following changes:

First change the `Singleton` class, so that it's `singleton` field is lazily created in the `getInstance()` call, notice that this method now needs to be `synchronized`. You need this to be able to reset the field.

```
public final class Singleton {
  private static Singleton singleton = null;

  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
    }
    return singleton;
  }

  private Singleton() {
    if (!new File("maybeIExist.txt").exists()) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    System.out.println("stuff");
  }
}
```

Next, in your test class you can reset the `singleton` field in a `@Before` method to `null` using reflection:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.notNullValue;

public class SingletonTest {

  @Before
  public void resetSingleton() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field instance = Singleton.class.getDeclaredField("singleton");
    instance.setAccessible(true);
    instance.set(null, null);
  }

  @Test
  public void singletonCanFindFile() throws Exception {
    final Path path = Paths.get("maybeIExist.txt");

    Files.createFile(path);
    final Singleton instance = Singleton.getInstance();
    assertThat(instance, notNullValue());
    Files.deleteIfExists(path);
  }

  @Test(expected = ExceptionInInitializerError.class)
  public void singletonCannotFindFile() throws Exception {
      final Singleton instance = Singleton.getInstance();
      fail("no exception thrown!");
  }
}
```