# Using JUnit with Groovy classloader

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I have a simple Groovy test class using JUnit

```
class GroovyJunitTest {
  @Test
  void test() {
    println this.class.getClassLoader().toString()
  }
}
```

This prints out

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
```

which means that Java classloader is used.

I run the test with both Intellij IDE and using gradle test. The same result is in both cases.

Is there a way to configure JUnit to use Groovy classloader?

Comment: How are you running it? from any ide? or build tools?

Comment: @Rao just updated my question

Comment: Please see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102/using-different-classloaders-for-different-junit-tests

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem and I used https://github.com/bitstrings/junit-clptr
to load my `custom classloader`.

*Note*: this is no longer supported by the crator however for me it did work out. Anyway if it's to important to trust an outside source you can take it as an inspiration and define your own annotation that will let you choose your custom classloader